# Flutter Provider rebuilds unnecessary widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am building a mobile app with provider architecture on flutter.

As per the design, I am using a model with changeNotifier which has a list of objects in it.

Whenever there is a change in one of the list object the whole list is getting rebuilt which not supposed to be.

To simulate this, I have created a simple app like below. The top line is a list of items, whereas the bottom one is the detailed widget. But whenever I tap both the list widget and the detailed widget is getting rebuilt.

Here is the source code.
[Github Link](https://github.com/mahiznan/flutter_provider)

Here is the sample screenshot
[image: Image Screenshot]

Here are my questions.

1. How to listen only to the child object?
2. What is the mistake I have made here?

Answer (score 0):

The provider state management package offerers consumers. When using consumers you have the option to pass in in a child widget which you do don't wish to rebuild. And a builder methods which then accepts the child(which is mostly in this state static and doesn't need rebuilding) together with the widget which are to be rebuilt in your case the bottom detail card if I'm not mistaking. You can lesrn more from the docs provided they're very self explanatory. https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/README.md

Also the medium post in this link explains a lot on how the provider package works.  https://medium.com/flutter-nyc/a-closer-look-at-the-provider-package-993922d3a5a5

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think you need to worry about the full rebuild, but if it bothers you, there's a Selector widget which you can use to listen to specific value of the item in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bit late, But for anyone has this problem.
**Provider** is just a dependency injection framework, You can not use it for state management (alone).
You should've provided us with a sample of your code, but I will assume that You're using **Provider** with **ChangeNotifier**.
In this situation You just have to use the **Consumer** Widget that  have a **build** function inside this function You put your that is gonna be rebuilt..
[Here is a Medium article](https://medium.com/@aruny3/how-to-use-changenotifier-in-flutter-440371617b8c)

Another way is to use a combination of **Provider** and **Streams** and you can use **StreamBuilder** Widget the same way you use **Consumer**..